# Obtain the value of function now() in Google spredsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google script sheet, in cell A1 I input the function now() and returns current time (e.g. 13:00). I want to fix the value. But if I make any change in the cell, the value will be changed. What I can do is to copy cell A1 and selective paste value in cell B1 and then change the format of B1 as time. Is there any function that can obtain the value in A1 and fix it in another cell?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another question I don't understand but perhaps:

1. select the `another cell`
2. key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If I have misunderstood, perhaps [Google Docs time stamp?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39622/google-docs-time-stamp) from Web Apps may be hepful.